# how to write step definition for cucumber given condition using maven project

Tags: maven, cucumber

I am new to Maven and not able to write steps for below cucumber feature

Feature: Random String.
Scenario: Non-capturing group
Given I have a beautiful home
Given I have an attractive home
Given I have a big home

Answer (score 0):

I have added the project code as well as the maven project structure image below. I believe that you must watch some quick tutorials related to the cucumber basic. So that you will be to understanding the keywords that we usually use while creating the feature file. If you have any other question then do let me know sir. I am glad to help you.

[image: Maven Project Structure]

**Runner.java**

```
package runners;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features="features",glue="stepdefs")
public class Runner  extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests
{

}
```

**StepDefinition.java**

```
package stepdefs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinition 
{
    
    List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String actualRandomString = "";

    @Given("^I have a random string - (.*)$")
    public void given(String randomString)
    {
        actualRandomString = randomString.trim();
    }
    
    @When("I check for the non matching group")
    public void when()
    {
        String regex = "I have a(n)? (beautiful|attractive) home";
          System.out.printf("Regex: %s, Input: %s%n", regex, actualRandomString);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(actualRandomString);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.printf("Group zero, start= %s, end= %s, match= '%s'%n",
                        matcher.start(), matcher.end(), matcher.group());
                for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("Group number: %s, start: %s, end: %s, match= '%s'%n%n",
                            i, matcher.start(i), matcher.end(i), matcher.group(i));
                }
            }
    }
    
    
    @When("I should get the desired outcome")
    public void then()
    {
        System.out.println("Verifying the outcome");
    }
    
}
```

**random-string.feature**

```
    Feature: Random String
      I want to use this feature file to test the functionality of random strings
    
      Scenario Outline: Verification of random string for non matching groups
        Given I have a random string - <Random Strings>
        When I check for the non matching group 
        Then I should get the desired outcome
        
        Examples: 
          | Random Strings |
          |I have a beautiful home|
          |I have an attractive home|
          |I have a big home|
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Cucumber Java Maven Dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.10</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
    
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. It worked.. I am going through the videos and tutorials to learn Cucumber..